# Facebook groups posting - security issue

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to make an application for my colleague. Since he has many fb groups, he wants to be able send posts automaticaly (not spam) to selected groups. I have written a small script which obtain `access_token` and then this script sends the posts.

The problem is, that facebook probably things that it's an unauthorized posting from his account which is not..

Here is the message he gets after tried to send a post to one of his groups:

> We’ve Detected Suspicious Account Activity
>      It looks like your account has been spreading spam due to another person or website gaining access to some of your sensitive account
>   information.
>
> Sometimes this happens when spammers create a fake Page that offers you a great deal (ex: free plane tickets) in return for a
>   specific piece of information from your account, like an access token.
>
> We’ve secured your account, and will help clean up any recent account activity that didn’t come directly from you.

Is there a way to tell the facebook that no unwanted website or person gaining his info?

```
def post_to_1_group(test):

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
    groups = graph.get_object("me/groups")
    group_id = groups['data'][1]['id']
    graph.put_object(group_id, "feed", message=test)
```

Comment: There is not. It is our spam tool that detects that he is doing something that triggers our spam tools.

Comment: I tried only one post to one group.. How it could be considered as a spam? This app is definitely not for spam purposes. It is for advertising groups.

Comment: Advertising in groups I would say the definition of spam is

Comment: Btw, thanks for answers WizKid. Yes, in some point of view, but it is not SPAM if you put your advertisement into group created for advertising - the group is created for adverising implies that advertisement is not unwanted there. But still. I made only one post to one group which definitely can't be considered as a spam :) EDIT: I'm not good at english - I do not mean commercial advertisements, I mean "I will buy a cheap couch."-like advertisements.